# Git - How to reset local branch to remote branch without adding a remote

Tags: git, github

I handle a lot of github pull requests all day long and use the following pattern to checkout associated branches in order to test the changes:

```
git checkout -b user-branch master
git pull git@github.com:user/repo.git branch
```

Now sometimes the developer who made the PR amends some revisions and I would like to reset my local branch to reflect those changes without deleting and re-creating the local branch (this often adds significant build time).

I can add a temporary remote like this

```
git remote add tmp git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

and then reset the branch

```
git reset --hard tmp/branch
```

and remove the remote.

But surely there must be a better solution without the need to git remote add, right ?

Answer (score 0):

I would fetch proposed changes directly:

```
git fetch -f git@github.com:user/repo.git branch:tmp/remote-user-branch
```

and then merge `master` with the `tmp/remote-user-branch` with regular `git merge`

`-f` is required to forcibly override `tmp/remote-user-branch` if it exists already

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear in my question, I meant I would like to not have to 'git remote add' anything at all.

Comment: My solution doesn't require any additional remote. Simply fetch required changes by specifying URL and a temporary branch. `git fetch` (as well as other git network-related utilities) can work with pre-configured remotes or directly with URLs.

Comment: So take the URL of a given forked repo with a merge request and use it right in `git fetch` w/o prior creation of a remote.

Comment: tmp is a remote just added with git add remote. Maybe I don't understand what you mean but if I replace tmp with git@github.com:user/repo.git in your command line I get fatal: Couldn't find remote ref git@github.com

Comment: `git fetch -f git@github.com:user/repo.git branch:git@github.com:user/repo.git/user-branch` yields `fatal: Invalid refspec 'user-branch:git@github.com:user/repo.git/branch'`

Comment: Surely invalid. The argument `branch:git@github.com:user/repo.git/user-branch` consists of two parts splitted by the (first) `:`. The first part `branch` - is the name of the branch in the remote (user's github) repository. The second part (in my example `tmp/remote-user-branch`, in your - `git@github.com:user/repo.git/user-branch`) is the name of the branch under which the changes from that `branch` will be saved locally. You should use a simple name, valid for a git branch to store the changes. After the merge is complete you can remove that branch using `git branch -D <chosen name>`.